Is Reality blind and unresponsive to our conscious interaction?
There are 2 different aspects of universe we experience. First one is physical laws that is not bound by good or bad, has zero emotional intelligence.Second one is from Ants to humans we consciously live through it.We have emotional sense of right or wrong. Life has survived so long on emotion less physical reality. Am I wrong, is reality responding to our consciousness or it is just cold matter, space,time interaction.

How could one convincingly prove this either way? In the absence of proof, I believe philosophy is divided on the question.

"There are 2 different aspects of universe we experience" - no, there is only one aspect we experience, and that's our subjective, conscious experience. The presence of an aspect of the universe that is different from conscious experience, is not experienced by us. When you touch a rock, for instance, all that you observe about the rock takes the form of subjective, conscious experience.

What do you mean by 'reality'? There are people who can talk their way out of a situation, and reality changes: the walls move if you push them. Or is the question another version of "Do we have free will"? And then, no two people share the exact same reality, and they may disagree as to what happened. One observer might say that you did that, another might say that the antagonist changed their mind when a car back-fired nearby. Yet another might believe it was the combination of your talk and the back-fire, that neither on their own would have changed the course of the future.

My body is part of reality, I believe, and it certainly responds to my consciousness. I presume that is not the question you are trying to ask, but I'm not sure what question you did intend. If you are referring to prayer and similar attempts to influence reality via pure will, some people believe that is possible but no evidence beyond the anecdotal has been presented to support that belief, and anecdotal evidence is subject to confirmation bias and other errors.
